# can I use it without creating locks in the root install dir?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to use a Conda installation that was installed by a user other than myself, and with the root installation directory having read only perms.

Supposedly this is doable in the latest version of Conda and the envs_dirs setting, but even with the envs_dirs setting set to a writable path, Conda still tries to create locks in the read only root install path. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future - https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1329

This issue addresses a multitude of problems with running shared user environments in Conda. As of time of this posting, it's partially supported and somewhat hacky, though check the link for status.